# C_Login fails in PKCS11 in C

Tags: c, linux, pkcs#11

Simple issue, but i don't know how to unlock USB Token(epass2003) ,I have try to read PKCS 11 but have no idea how to implement C_Login function for execution in c ,when i am using command line tool (Linux)to do that token is working perfectly fine but with c its not working I have used user type as CKU_USER, Can anyone have knowledge about this, please help

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. To make it easier for us to answer your question, it would help if you provided some more information. What have you tried? What error did you get? Can you provide a short, self-contained example of the problem you are seeing? See http://sscce.org/, http://whathaveyoutried.com/, and http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx for details on how to write a good question.

Answer (score 0):

you have to check the return values from the PKCS functions to see if there has been any errors. Try this way and see what happen. If the return code from C_login() is CKR_PIN_LOCKED, then it is clear that you should unlock your card.

```
CK_RV ret;

ret = C_OpenSession(slot, CKF_SERIAL_SESSION, NULL_PTR, NULL_PTR, &session); 

if (ret  != CKR_OK){
   error_message(ret);
   return;
}

readPIN("Intro PIN: ", pin, 4); 
ret = (f_C_Login)(hSession,CKU_USER, (unsigned char *) pin,strlen(pin));
if (ret != CKR_OK){
   closeSessions(slot);
   error_message(ret);
   return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A token can get locked due to a certain number of failed login (for TrustKey it is 10). There are provider specific utilities to unlock tokens. You could check Feitian site. There is some pointer to this kind of problem in Gooze forum (though not exactly). Your problem looks quite like a token lock problem.